# Instances of Shevua Shechal Bo

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, halacha-theory, tisha-bav, nine-days

Does the concept "Shevua Shechal Bo" come up within the context of halacha or hashkafa in any area other than the the week leading up to Tisha B'Av? It just seems like a unique measure for a period of time, unlike say a 7 day period for mourning which matches a full week. I'm wondering if there are any justifications for why it applies to Tisha B'Av and seemingly nowhere else.

Comment: Shavua Shechal Bo is too a 7 day period of mourning that happens to always start on Sunday. It's much smoother to start on Sunday because you don't have to have a nonmourning day of Shabbat in the middle

Comment: @DoubleAA But could it ever work out to be a full 7 days? (whether in our current fixed calendar cycle or the ones determined beforehand via witnesses). Tisha B'Av would then get pushed to the next Sunday. So it would be a period of 7 days (if Shabbat is included) of intense mourning before a day which has even more intense mourning.

Comment: Shavua Shechal Bo is always the whole week. See Taanit 30a. There are two opinions for when to observe the mourning: from Rosh Chodesh until tisha bav, or the whole week of tisha bav. We rule leniently both ways and just observe the week of tisha bav until the fast, so we don't really observe the whole Shavua Shechal Bo

Comment: Ashkenazi minhag of selichos is another example of shavua shechal bo (unless there's less than 4 days in which case it starts the week before)

Comment: Perhaps the difference between regular aveilus and tisha bav is that by aveilus the first day is peak of mourning, (onen, etc.) Then there's the first 3 days which are in between, then the last 4 days are the least. Whereas by tisha bav it's the opposite, with the days leading up being less mourning, and the last day, Tisha bav, being the peak. So if the point is to lead up to a peak instead of away from a peak then we try not to have a break in the middle for shabbos. This would maybe explain selichos as well, since they lead up to Rosh hashanah

Comment: @Chatzkel "if the point is to lead up to a peak instead of away from a peak then we try not to have a break in the middle for shabbos." I don't understand this at all. If the point it to lead away from a peak we should also try not to have a break. Why would we ever want a break?

Comment: I was proposing, that perhaps when your preparing for a climax and working towards that, then each day is connected to the prior day and to the next day and a break would push you back and you'd need to restart. Whereas if your leading away from a peak then each day is not necessarily connected to the next and a break is not detrimental

Comment: @Chatzkel I have no idea why that would be the case. Paths up and paths down are both paths.